# How to merge array two level become one level in php

Tags: php, arrays

halo everyone. now I'm trying to merge array inside array after query from SQL.. and the result like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["building_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["building_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["building_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

I already tried to use this code

```
$result=[];
foreach($bulding_ids as $arr)
{
  $result  = array_merge($arr['building_id'],$result);
}
```

but maybe that is not a answer

I want to that array become like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Can I make like that?

Comment: What did you try ? And yes you can if it's your only question

Comment: So you want the value of every 'building_id' key in your array converted to integer?

Comment: @Fjarlaegur. just display the value for "building_id".. evendo the type is string or int. is ok

Comment: @executable i update my question with code that i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$result = array_column($building_ids, 'building_id');
```

> `array_column()` returns the values from a single column of the input,
>   identified by the `column_key`. Optionally, an `index_key` may be
>   provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from
>   the `index_key` column of the input array.

This eliminates the need for a loop.

Output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }
```

---

The only downside of this, is that all of the building ID's will be stored as strings. If this is a problem for your application, you can easily use `array_map()` to convert them to ints.

Directly after the line above, do this:

```
$result = array_map('intval', $result);
```

> `array_map()` returns an array containing all the elements of `array1`
>   after applying the callback function to each one. The number of
>   parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number
>   of arrays passed to the `array_map()`

Output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

---

You can also make this a single line solution:

```
$result = array_map('intval', array_column($building_ids, 'building_id'));
```

But in my opinion this looks a bit more messy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse every element in your first array and return the id. Then you convert it into int type. Finally, you save the new value into a new array.

```
<?php
$bulding_ids[] = ["Building_id" => "1"];
$bulding_ids[] = ["Building_id" => "2"];
$bulding_ids[] = ["Building_id" => "3"];

$result = array();

foreach($bulding_ids as $val){
    $result[] = (int)$val['Building_id'];
} 

var_dump($result);
```